# Singular matrix and wedge product

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

If I have a singular matrix $X$ with components $X_{\mu\nu}$:

$t^{\nu}X_{\mu\nu}=0$

By considering now $X_{\mu\nu}$'s as components of a 2-form can I say that:

$X\wedge X=0$  ?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition on $X$ is that it has a kernel, and that by itself does not mean that
$X \wedge X$ doesn't have to vanish.  For instance in five dimensions, you could have 
$$X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then letting $t = (0,0,0,0,1)$, your condition is satisfied, but $X \wedge X$ is not zero.

However, it is true in $2n$ dimensions that a non-zero $t$ exists if and only if $X^{\wedge n} = 0$.  That's because $X^{\wedge n}$ is proportional to the [Pfaffian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) of $X$, which is a certain square root of the determinant of $X$.  (In odd dimensions, the determinant of an antisymmetric matrix is zero by calculation, while the Pfaffian is set to zero by definition.  So $t$ always exists in this case.)

Comment: Typo? You meant $X^{\wedge n}$, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks t3suji!  This is the second time that you have improved my answer.

Comment: thank you very much, I felt that what I was calculating `$X\wedge X$` looks like a Pfaffian but I did not see the relationship. Now I can continue my study of the Plebanski action :-)